# JavaScript Finding the x and y coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to use the canvas api on a map designed in Adobe illustrator that is 600px by 600px. Let's say there's a pizza store on the map. How can I find the x and y coordinates of it?  sure, I know I could do trial and error, but if there's going to be a lot of different points I want to connect, I need a faster and more accurate way to get the x and y coordinates. Is there a way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434757/how-do-i-get-the-coords-of-an-image

Comment: right now it's a jpg. Is it format dependent?  Preferably, I would like to know how to find out the x and y regardless of the format.

Comment: Voting to close; in what way is this [related to programming](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: @Phrogz how is this related to programming? well, it depends on the solution. I thought it might be possible to use JavaScript event listener (i.e. on some sort of mouse move with offsets) that could reveal location expressed in x and y coordinates, except I don't know how to write it.

Comment: @Phrogz in actual fact, before you came along, someone did post a script (now deleted) that I couldn't get to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the image in Photoshop (presumably you have this, if you have Illustrator).
2. Open the Info palette; click on the "XY" region and pick "Pixels" from the popup menu.
3. Move the mouse over the map item; record the X/Y coordinate at this location.
4. Rinse/repeat.

Comment: thanks a lot. as mentioned in my comment above, I was expecting to have to use some sort of javascript